# Is it possible to bind a windows key combination to currently open application?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, keymap

I use launchy on every box that I have to interact with for more than a few hours a day, and it certainly makes me more efficient, but I want more. I would like to have a key combination that would take a window that I use frequently, and is always open such as mRemote or FAR manager, and bring it to the foreground.

I have been alt-tabbing around forever, and it's getting old if there are more than a few windows open. Anyone have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 4):

You probably want [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Answer (score 2):

With Windows 7, Windows Key + 1 opens or minimizes or activates the first pinned application on the taskbar.

Answer (score 0):

There's a great Autohotkey script that assigns CapsLock (although that is configurable) as a window switcher which responds to typing the first few letters of an open application. Just hit enter to bring to front.

[lifehacker- iswitchw](http://lifehacker.com/5278802/iswitchw-finds-windows-as-you-type)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a shortcut to your application and set a shortcut key (-combination) for it under the Shortcut tab of the property sheet. Then click the shortcut to start your application. When it's running, the shortcut key will switch to it.

(may not work with complex applications where the first window they create is not the one you want to switch to)